# nginx proxy_pass if pm2 is running

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, pm2

I'm new in nginx and need a specific configuration.

I have a node.js (express) page, that runs via pm2 and everything works fine.

But now I want to use nginx for:

1. handle static files
2. open a static html (maintenance) page with server status 503 if the node.js site is down.

I found some solutions to handle static files, but no one to handle the maintenance mode during update/restart and down phase.

Can anyone help me, or give me a "nice" workaround?

THX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about it the other way around, and have nginx serve a proper maintenance page if the service is unavailable

```
error_page 500 502 503 504 /custom_50x.html;

location = /custom_50x.html {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    internal;
}
```